# How to extract data from HTML lists and tables from an external html document?

Tags: jquery, html, external

I am fairly new to jquery and still grasping the basics, but I have managed to use the .load function to extract a table from an external html document. However the issue I have is that when I display this external html in my index.html, it displays the entire table, therefore how would I go about only extracting and displaying a specific piece of data such as 10° only from the table?

External Html is as follows. (I am not allowed to change the html, ie I cant add ID's etc.)

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<th id="tbl241id1_0" scope="row">fri 11 june</th>
<td headers="e134567_0 e1345670_1">
<td headers="e134567_0 e1345670_2">10°C / -1°C</td>
<td headers="e134567_0 e1345670_3">4:30 am / 4:42 pm</td>
<td headers="e134567_0 e1345670_4">8:50 am / 5:13 pm</td>
<td headers="e134567_0 e1345670_5">1 (High)</td>
</tr>
```

This is how I have tried to work around this, but It still retrieves nothing.

```
 $("#showWeather").load("/info_weather.html tbody ").map (function(){
//displayed the weather table into index.html

var $temps = $(this); 

return{

text: $temps.find(':nth-child (3)').text() 

};


}).get();
```

I am assuming the mark up above is incorrect, Any ideas guys. Thanks.

Comment: fiddle it , then easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#showWeather").load("/info_weather.html tbody ", function(){
    console.log($('td:contains("10°C")').html());
})
```

Comment: No, why not? Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AEvJr/. Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#showWeather").load("/info_weather.html tbody ", function(){
    console.log($('td:nth(1)').html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty brittle. If the source markup ever changes, your code won't work anymore. However, you can [select by attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in jQuery. Try this:

`$("#showWeather").load("/info_weather.html [headers='e134567_0 e1345670_2']");`

This code should load only the td that contains the data you're targeting.

In general, use attribute selectors to target DOM elements in a more fine-grained way.